# Derive mean value property of harmonic function using this method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, wave-equation

We can view harmonic function $u(x,y,z)$ as a wave function that does not depend on time $t$. Let $\overline{u}(r)$ be its average value on the circle with radius $r$.

Assume we have proved that it satisfies $0=(\overline{u})_{rr}+2\frac{1}{r}(\overline{u})_r$.

I think it remains to show that $\overline{u}$ is constant so that $\overline{u}$ equals $u(0)$, which is equivalent to show $(\overline{u})_r=0$. We can see $0$ is one solution of the ODE, but I cannot disprove that others are not.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=\overline{u}$.

$v_{rr}+\frac{2}{r} v_r=0$, so $\frac{d}{dr} \left ( e^{2 \log(r)} v_r \right ) =0$, so $r^2 v_r=C$, so $v_r=\frac{C}{r^2}$, so $v=C/r+A$.

This is the general solution to the equation on any interval not containing $r=0$. This means that if you delete the origin, then there *is* a nonconstant radial function which satisfies the ODE. However, this function is singular at the origin. If you assume the function is not singular at the origin, then you must have $C=0$ in which case $v=A$ as desired.

Note that this singular solution does not furnish any contradiction to the mean value theorem as it is correctly formulated (the domain of the harmonic function must contain the *entire* ball whose boundary is the sphere in question).

Answer (score 0):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

I thought it might be instructive to show that if $\bar u(a)$ is the average value, taken over a sphere of radius $a$, of a harmonic function $u$, then $\bar u(a)$ is constant, independent of the radius of the sphere.

Let $V$ be a sphere of radius $a$ centered at $\vec r$ and let $S$ be its boundary described by $|\vec r-\vec r'|=a$.  The outer unit normal on $S$ at $\vec r'$ is given by $\hat n'=-\frac1a (\vec r-\vec r')$

Let $G(\vec r|\vec r')=\frac{1}{4\pi |\vec r-\vec r'|}$ be the Green Function (or alternatively the Green's Function) for Laplace' Equation so that $G$ satisfies

$$\nabla^2 G(\vec r|\vec r')=\delta(\vec r-\vec r') \tag 1$$

Note that on the sphere, we have

$$\left.\left(G(\vec r|\vec r')\right)\right|_{S}=\frac{1}{4\pi a} \tag 2$$

and

$$\left.\left(\nabla' G(\vec r|\vec r')\right)\right|_{S}=- \frac{\hat n'}{4\pi a^2} \tag 3$$

Using Green's Identity, we can write

$$\int_{V}\left(u(\vec r')\nabla'^2 G(\vec r|\vec r')-G(\vec r|\vec r')\nabla'^2 u(\vec r')\right)dV'=\oint_{S}\left(u(\vec r')\nabla' G(\vec r|\vec r')-G(\vec r|\vec r')\nabla' u(\vec r')\right)\cdot \hat n'dS' \tag 4$$

Since $u$ is harmonic, and since $G$ satisfies $(1)$, the left-hand side of $(4)$ becomes

$\int_{V}\left(u(\vec r')\nabla'^2 G(\vec r|\vec r')-G(\vec r|\vec r')\nabla'^2 u(\vec r')\right)dV'=-u(\vec r) \tag 5$.

We next exploit the fact that $G$ and its normal derivative are constant on the sphere as given by $(2)$ and $(3)$.  Then, the first term on the right-hand side of $(4)$ can be simplified as

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{S}u(\vec r')\nabla' G(\vec r|\vec r')\cdot \hat n'dS' &=-\frac{1}{4\pi a^2}\oint_S u(\vec r')\,dS' \tag 6
\end{align}$$

while the second term on the right-hand side of $(1)$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{S}G(\vec r|\vec r')\nabla' u(\vec r')\cdot \hat n'dS'&=\frac{1}{4\pi a}\oint_S \nabla u(\vec r')\cdot \hat n'\,dS'\\\\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi a}\int_V \nabla'^2 u(\vec r')\,dV'\\\\
&=0 \tag 7
\end{align}$$

Therefore, putting $(4)-(7)$ together, we find that

$$u(\vec r)=\frac{1}{4\pi a^2}\oint_S u(\vec r')\,dS'$$

which states that the average of the harmonic function, taken over a sphere of radius $a$ that is centered at $\vec r$, is equal to $u(\vec r)$, the value of $u$ at the center of the sphere.

Inasmuch as the value of $u(\vec r)$ for any $\vec r$ depends in no way on the radius of a sphere that we constructed, then the average cannot depend on this radius.  It is therefore independent of both $a$ and coordinate variables rendering it constant, as was to be shown.

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

Here, we will show that if $\bar u(a)$ is the average value, taken over a sphere of radius $a$, of a harmonic function $u$, and $\bar u(a)$ satisfies the ODE

$$\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{d}{da}\left(a^2\frac{d\bar u(a)}{da}\right)=0 \tag{8}$$

then $\bar u$ is a constant, independent of the radius $a$.

We assume that $(8)$ is true.  If so, then we have

$$\frac{d}{da}\left(a^2\frac{d\bar u(a)}{da}\right)=0\implies \frac{d\bar u(a)}{da}=-B/a^2 \implies \bar u(a)=A+Ba^{-1}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are integration constants.

Next, we note that $\bar u(a)= \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\Omega} u(\vec r') \,d\Omega'$, where $\Omega$ is the solid angle of the sphere.  Since $u$ is bounded inside the sphere, then

$$\lim_{a\to 0}\bar u(a)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\Omega}\,\lim_{a\to 0} u(\vec r') \,d\Omega'$$

must be finite.  We conclude, therefore, that we must have $B=0$ and that $\bar u$ is independent on the radius $a$, as was to be shown.

---